# jQuery - How to get the address text when a Google Maps places autocomplete is validated

Tags: jquery, google-maps, validation, autocomplete, textinput

I would like to know how to get the address text once a Google Maps places autocomplete is validated. For example, let's assume that while filling the text input up, the autocomplete list shows and when selecting one of its items (whether by hitting the direction keys in order to move to the wanted item then hitting the Enter key, or even by just making a mouse click on it), the selected address would be displayed in the console log.
Here is an example for a better illustration:

[image]

Here, I need to console log the address "Paris France" once it's selected.

This is my relevant HTML code:

```
<input type='text' id='nouvelleAdresse'>
```

And this is my relevant JavaScript code:

```
var options = {
                    componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
                };
var autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("nouvelleAdresse"), options);
autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
                function fillInAddress() {
                    var place1 = autocomplete1.getPlace();
                }
```

Actually, I could make it by simply adding the code below:

```
$(document).on('change', '#nouvelleAdresse', function() {
                console.log('the address: '+$(this).val())
            });
```

However, that gives me the same result when not selecting any of the autocomplete list items (or even when clicking outside the text input).
So, again, I aim to console log the address **only** when selecting it from the autocomplete list. Any idea?

Comment: What is an "Echap" key?

Comment: Perhaps just log the value in the `#nouvelleAdresse` when the `place_changed` event fires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it! I've just changed the code block below:

```
function fillInAddress() {
                var place1 = autocomplete1.getPlace();
            }
```

to this one:

```
function fillInAddress() {
                    var place1 = autocomplete1.getPlace();
                    console.log('the adress: '+$('#nouvelleAdresse').val())
                }
```